# Hibernate creates duplicate table names (case sensitivity issue)

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a restored MySQL database that contains lowercase table names. My @JPA table names are often camelCase. When I start my tomcat server, Hibernate automatically creates duplicate tablenames. I will start out with for example:

`country`

and after tomcat starts, I have

`country`

`Country`

I have set  `lower_case_table_names = 1`

in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`

`@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name="Country",indexes={
    @Index(name="countryURLLabel", columnList="URLLabel"),
    @Index(name="country_url",columnList="url")
})
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="country.getByCountryCode", query="select c from Country c where c.countryCode = :countryCode")
})
@FetchProfiles({
    @FetchProfile(name = FetchProfileName.OFFER_DETAIL, fetchOverrides = {
        @FetchProfile.FetchOverride(entity = Country.class, association = "defaultLanguage", mode = FetchMode.JOIN)
    })
})
@NaturalIdCache(region=CacheRegion.NATURAL)
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE,region=CacheRegion.COUNTRY)
public class Country implements Serializable, GeoLocation, Comparable<Country>, URLLocation{`

Comment: could you attach your Country entity class? and your hibernate configuration.

Comment: Why do you let Hibernate create tables in the first place, since they already exist?

Comment: fair question. Still, this is not very nice behavior